# Advanced Installer: Custom Logic behind Installation Progress Dialog (ProgressDlg)

Tags: advanced-installer

We have a bug in our Advanced Installer that I have been tasked to track down.  It happens while the Progress Dialog (ProgressDlg) is being displayed.  I am pretty sure I know what is causing the error, but... I really don't know anything about Advanced Installer.  Where, how do I find the logic that is happening while this dialog is being displayed?

Meaning... as a user is doing the install, on this dialog, the status bar moves along, and the name / title of each task it's doing being the scenes is displayed (setup IIS, install web files, install the database, etc etc etc).

But, inside the Advanced Installer interface, I am just not seeing where or how to find the code that is executed while the Progress Dialog is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know the functionality you are referring to is controlled by the Windows Installer service.

All the Windows Installer actions inserted into your MSI setup have an action description text you can configure from ActionText table of the Table Editor view of your setup project.

Each custom action (defined by you in the project) that modifies the system also has an action text which you can configure from Custom Actions view of your setup project.

During installation when an action is executed the Windows Installer service fetches its action text from ActionText table and display it on progress dialog.

If you found a bug in this functionality I think it would be better post your question on [Advanced Installer forums](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/).

Hopefully this was helpful for you.

Comment: thanks! The bug is ours, not theirs.  It's in one of our custom actions.